# jquery mobile back button does not seem to be working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Here is the link to the app i am working on http://diligentbrainteam.com/fdd/. Try entering some zip code (2450), and the transition to next page is using 'changePage' method. The back button on the second page does not seem to be working. The URL is always the same, as if the new page is being loaded in the current page. Any suggestions on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second page you have `<div class="left back-btn"><a href="#" data-rel="back">Back</a></div>` .Since the `href` is linked to the same page its not going anywhere. Try to change the `href="#"` to the starting page and it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are setting "changeHash" to "false" in your changePage call. See http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html

Comment: but in the `html` still she/he is refering to the same right? So i think unless location where `href=` is pointing is changed it will not go back to the `index.html` or whatever page

Comment: I thought when we use data-rel="back", jquery mobile takes on page back. I am saying this because, there are more pages and for all of the them the URL in the browser is the same. but the previous page would be different. For example, if you search by 'Surry Hills', we get some results back. When we click on one of the results, the back button should refer to previous page. I mean I can construct the URL, but it would be much easier if jquery mobile would take one page back.

Comment: data-rel="back" just tells jQuery Mobile to create a button that calls history.back(). It's equivalent to clicking the browser back button yourself. Setting changeHash to "false" tells changePage to replace the current page state without adding an entry to history. So clicking the back button does nothing.